# read query stringfrom mvc url

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

This maybe a stupid question but i've come from an asp.net background so reading a querystring is pretty easy, not to sure how I should be doing it with mvc.

Lets say I have a url that looks like https://localhost/Account/Verify?code=3ae9a4f4-84d3-4686-b5a6-3e53e008537b

How do I read the code=3ae9a...........?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Request.QueryString["CODE"]
```

That's it :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it very simple.

```
string codeValue = "";
if(Request.QueryString["code"] != null)
{
    codevalue = Request.QueryString["code"]
}
```

And if you use Guid, like in this case, just create new Guid from value.

Comment: buda, sorry but this is a TOO COMPLICATED ANSWER for such simple question :)

Comment: Probably, but what if value does not exists, application crashes. :)

Comment: from a quality prespective, YES. but note that he is only asking for the way to read it :)

BTW, I like people who care about handling exceptions early. +1 for that :)